# How correct is the use of Rich Snippet Person in a staff?

Tags: seo, microdata, google-rich-snippets

I'm tagging the staff of a medical facility and I would like to add Microdata. But I'm not sure how to label a staff.

It may be so:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Person">

    <h3><span itemprop="affiliation">Marckay</span> Staff</h3>

    <h4 itemprop="title">Medico Fisiatra</h4>
        <span itemprop="name">Dra. María Sylvina Iaconianni</span>
        <span itemprop="name">Dr. Gustavo Adolfo Andrade</span>
        <span itemprop="name">Dr. Matías Merkusa</span>

    <h4 itemprop="title">Area Médica-Pediatria</h4>
        <span itemprop="name">Dra. Cecilia Petriz</span>

    <h4 itemprop="title">Kinesiologia</h4>
        <span itemprop="name">Lic. Constanza Alonso</span>
        <span itemprop="name">Lic. Maria Carolina Alvarez</span>
        <span itemprop="name">Lic. Cristina Elizabeth Amuchastegui</span>
        <span itemprop="name">Lic. Matias Damian Brito</span>
        <span itemprop="name">Lic. Maria Lourdes Campos</span>
        <span itemprop="name">Lic. Silvia Teresa Gimenez</span>
        <span itemprop="name">Lic. Magdalena Ines Macagno</span>
        <span itemprop="name">Lic. Rocio Martinez</span>
        <span itemprop="name">Lic. Jonathan Medina</span>
        <span itemprop="name">Lic. Sergio Mercado</span>

</div>
```

Or may be:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Person">

    <h3><span itemprop="affiliation">Marckay</span> Staff</h3>

    <h4 itemprop="title">Medico Fisiatra</h4>
        <span itemprop="name">Dra. María Sylvina Iaconianni</span>
        <span itemprop="name">Dr. Gustavo Adolfo Andrade</span>
        <span itemprop="name">Dr. Matías Merkusa</span>
</div>
<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Person">

    <h4 itemprop="title">Area Médica-Pediatria</h4>
        <span itemprop="name">Dra. Cecilia Petriz</span>

</div>
<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Person">

    <h4 itemprop="title">Kinesiologia</h4>
        <span itemprop="name">Lic. Constanza Alonso</span>
        <span itemprop="name">Lic. Maria Carolina Alvarez</span>
        <span itemprop="name">Lic. Cristina Elizabeth Amuchastegui</span>
        <span itemprop="name">Lic. Matias Damian Brito</span>
        <span itemprop="name">Lic. Maria Lourdes Campos</span>
        <span itemprop="name">Lic. Silvia Teresa Gimenez</span>
        <span itemprop="name">Lic. Magdalena Ines Macagno</span>
        <span itemprop="name">Lic. Rocio Martinez</span>
        <span itemprop="name">Lic. Jonathan Medina</span>
        <span itemprop="name">Lic. Sergio Mercado</span>

</div>
```

Or else I imagine a `<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Person">` per person, but a tangle would be done.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your examples, one person would have several names.

You need a separate item for each person.

```html
<div>

    <h3><span>Marckay</span> Staff</h3>

    <h4>Medico Fisiatra</h4>
        <div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Person">
          <span itemprop="name">Dra. María Sylvina Iaconianni</span>
        </div>
        <div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Person">
          <span itemprop="name">Dr. Gustavo Adolfo Andrade</span>
        </div>
        <div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Person">
          <span itemprop="name">Dr. Matías Merkusa</span>
        </div>

    <h4>Area Médica-Pediatria</h4>
        <div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Person">
          <span itemprop="name">Dra. Cecilia Petriz</span>
        </div>

</div>
```

(The same applies for Schema.org’s [`Person` type](http://schema.org/Person), which you might want to use instead of Data-Vocabulary.org.)

Comment: I would have to assign a `title` to each person also

Comment: @nicogaldo: You could do this by giving the `h4` an ID and use it in a `itemref` attribute on each Person.